# egit not cloning submodules Recursively

Tags: git, version-control, egit

I have a repo configured with recursive sub-modules in GIT.

For example, `Repo A` has `Repo B` as a submodule which itself has `Repo C` as sub-module.

When I clone `Repo A` from eGit, it does not do a recursive clone and checkout like `--recurse-submodules` switch does in CLI. I only get the `Repo B`, but not `Repo C`.
Is this a known problem, any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EGit User Guide for the 1.3 release doesn't explicitly state that it can be done.  Is it possible to select multiple submodules at once and then perform an action on the whole set?  Just throwing the idea out.  I'm not an EGit user, so I couldn't say.  I see that you've created bug 375426 over at eclipse.org (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375426).  Good luck.  Hopefully the folks who designed it will answer.

Comment: i hope it is fixed soon or some workaround available. really important for this to work for acceptance from our users. 5K users wont use CLI.

Comment: it is fixed!! "merged as 543c5238ae3578f37cb9ada36b95775fa564e41d" .. says the bug update. would a new Egit version be available now?

Comment: That's good news.  You may be able to put an update into the defect asking if they have a targeted release that you could expect to see it in (and a date).

Comment: latest nightly build fixes the issue.

Comment: The defect says it's targeted for 2.0 which is in June.  I believe you can download nightlies from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly .